# how to mock useUser this custom hook using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

Let's say we have a custom hook named useUser

```
const useUser = (): IUser => useContext(MiniAppContext).user;
```

Then it is used in another component

```
import { useUser } from '@ABC'

const { monitoring } = useUser(); // please note that monitoring is an object having property id
```

When we run test case, it shows

```
TypeError: xxxx.useUser is not a function
```

I used below codes to pass the unit test, but I know that this is good enough. Please let me know what the best practise for this. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

```
jest.mock('@ABC', () => ({
   userUser: () => ({monitoring: {}} as IUser)
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be to create a util function that mocks the custom hook:

```
import * as useUserHook from '@ABC';

function generateUseUserHook(mock?: IUser): IUser {
    const value: IUser = {
        monitoring: jest.fn(),
        // mock return value (you can use faker)
        ...mock
    };

    jest.spyOn(useUserHook, 'useUser').mockReturnValue(value);

    return value;
}
```

instead of `jest.mock`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. If I still want to use jest.mock, could you please check my updated part and see if it is good? thanks

Comment: And one more thing is monitoring is an object as well.